# How to set default selected checkbox in Ng Multiselect dropdown (Angular Control)

Tags: angular, angular6, dropdown

Here is the sample code, to create multiselect dropdown

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select'"
                   [data]="dropdownList"
                   [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
                   [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                   (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                   (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

while creating this multiselect dropdown, i wanted few of the check boxes to be selected by default (based on the data provided).
I tried binding the checkboxes using `[(ngModel)]="selectedItems"` property, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Can you provide the typescript code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you paste selectedItems, dropdownList and  dropdownSettings object?

> SelectedItems and dropdownList items should be same and
>   dropdownSettings should be having the correct idField and textField.